# Python iterator test error: TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python, iterator

trying to understand how iterator works. Below is my test, but I get an error in Iter(self) --  TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

```
class TestIter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __iter__(self):
        return Iter(self)


class Iter:
    def __int__(self, source):
        self.source = source

    def next(self):
        if self.source.value >= 10:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.source.value += 1
            return self.source.value

test = TestIter(5)
for i in test:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **exception TypeError**
>
> > Raised when an operation or function is applied to
> >     an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string
> >     giving details about the type mismatch.

In your case it was `__int__` which should have been `__init__`. And just as a suggestion, instead of using such a complicated way to build a iterator, just simply use one class and call it directly.

Example:

```
class Count:

    """Iterator that counts upward forever."""

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.num = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self): // This will go to infinity but you can applyyour own logic to
        num = self.num
        self.num += 1
        return num
```

Calling can be done by either this:

```
>>> c = Count()
>>> next(c)
0
```

Or this:

```
>>> for n in Count():
...     print(n)
...
0
1
2
(this goes on forever)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. Check `__int__` vs `__init__` in your `Iter`.

Because of the typo, you do not define the `__init__` and therefore you use the default, which indeed takes no arguments.